# Using Sklearn, Category Predictions not working on the test data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

**Dataset**: I created a very simple dataset of "Supplier", "Item description" columns . This dataset has a list of item descriptions and preferred supplier for that item

**Requirement**: I would like to write a program that will take an "Item Description" and predict the "Supplier". To keep it very simple, I just have only 5 Unique supplier-Item Description combinations out of the 950 rows in the .txt file

**Issue**: The accuracy shows up 1 and confusing matrix shows no false positives. But when I give a new data, the prediction is wrong.

**Steps Done**

1. Read .txt for "Supplier" and "Item Description"
2. Label Encoder applied on the "Item Description"
3. train test and split

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.10)
```

4. Created a Pipeline for applying the TfidfVectorizer and MultinomialNB

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', vectorizer),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB())
                     ])
model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

5. fit model and predict :

```
y_pred=model.predict(X_test) 
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
acc= accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
# acc is 1.0 and the cm shows no false positives/negatgives
```

So far, things look ok

6. dumped the pickle

```
pickle.dump(model, open(r'supplier_predictions.pkl','wb'))
```

7. Tried prediction on a Item Description= 'Lego, Barbie and other Toy Items' ; I was expecting "Toys R Us"
8. The prediction was wrong, it came up as "Office Depot".

```
loadedModel = pickle.load(open("supplier_predictions.pkl","rb"))

new_items = {'ITEM_DESCRIPTION': ['Lego, Barbie and other Toy Items']}
new_X = pd.DataFrame(new_items, columns = ['ITEM_DESCRIPTION'])
new_y_pred=loadedModel.predict(new_X)
```

Can you please let me know
what I am doing wrong here to get the wrong prediction, new_y_pred for the test item description passed in (new_X)

This is my first ML code. I have tried debugging this by looking at various articles, but no luck.

Thanks

== Complete Code, if it is helpful ==

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import re     # librarie for cleaning data
import nltk   # library for NLP
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
import pickle

df=pd.read_csv('git_suppliers.txt', sep='\t')

# Prep the data - Item Description
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
words = stopwords.words("english")
df['ITEM_DESCRIPTION'] = df['ITEM_DESCRIPTION'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([stemmer.stem(i) for i in re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ", x).split() if i not in words]).lower())

# Feature Generation using the TF-IDF
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df= 3, stop_words="english", sublinear_tf=True, norm='l2', ngram_range=(1, 2))
final_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['ITEM_DESCRIPTION']).toarray()
final_features.shape
# final_features shows only 43 features - not going to use SelectKBest for such such less features count

#
# Split into training and test data
#
X = df['ITEM_DESCRIPTION']
y = df['SUPPLIER']
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelObj = LabelEncoder()
y=labelObj.fit_transform(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.10)
y_test_decoded=labelObj.inverse_transform(y_test)
#
# Create a pipeline, fit the model, predict for test data and save in pickle
#
pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', vectorizer),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB())
                     ])
model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict for test data
y_pred=model.predict(X_test) 

# Accuracy shows up as 1.0 and the confusion matrix shows no false positives/negatives
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
acc= accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
print(acc)

# Dump the model and lets predict for one item description, 
# for which i expect Toys R Us as the supplier/Seller
pickle.dump(model, open(r'supplier_predictions.pkl','wb'))
loadedModel = pickle.load(open("supplier_predictions.pkl","rb"))

new_items = {'ITEM_DESCRIPTION': ['Lego, Barbie and other Toy Items']}
new_X = pd.DataFrame(new_items, columns = ['ITEM_DESCRIPTION'])
new_y_pred=loadedModel.predict(new_X)  
labelObj.inverse_transform(new_y_pred)
### Shows Office Depot
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad - the input to the predict was wrong type. Passed in a series and it worked fine.

```
new_items = pd.Series(new_items) 
new_y_pred=loadedModel.predict(new_items) 
labelObj.inverse_transform(new_y_pred)
```